# how to create soap message using javascript for file uploading?

Tags: javascript, web-services, spring, soap

I am writing some web services and working with Spring at the server side.
How can I create soap messages using javascript to upload files and how is the server side implementation of this service?

Comment: Possible duplicate: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example-using-javascript

Comment: @Guy: constructing a soap message via javascript, yes.  But the question revolves around uploading a file through javascript via soap and to a Spring service.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you familiarize yourself with [MTOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTOM) for sending attachments over SOAP. An MTOM message can be created using any programming language. An example can be found here: http://www.crosschecknet.com/intro_to_mtom.php

Comment: thanks, but the example was for .NET. Actually I can't get how can I determine in my soap message which file I am going to upload(transfer).

Comment: Yes, but the concept of how to construct the message remain just the same. "which file I am going to upload" - sorry, don't understand your question.

Comment: see, I have the file path on client's side. now how can I transfer that file's content to my soap request (how can I generate the request)? as mentioned in the question's description, I want to generate the message using javascript, so I can't use libraries like axis, jaxb, etc.

Comment: @elfar, if your question is how to read a file from the browser's machine with JavaScript then you need to look into the [HTML5 file API](http://html5demos.com/file-api). Read the file, encode it with base64 (there are JavaScript libs for that) and use the base64 string in the SOAP message.