# Calling wsdl webservice in Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, wsdl

How do i call wsdl webservice in Phonegap? Is there any source code or any useful tutorial available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phonegap is a framework that helps in bridging the UI and the objective c code.

If you want to call the webservice you can either call it by using ajax or you can call the webservice directly from the objective c code.

You'll get lot of examples for Ajax based calls and objective c in internet.

These are few links to start with
[Simplest SOAP example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example-using-javascript)
http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap has nothing to do with what kind of Webservice you call... Webservice calls are typically done using jQuery.  PhoneGap just packages your code written in HTML, CSS and JavaScript in to an app.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Whizkid747..:)