# Javascript - Add and retrieve data from MS Dynamics CRM Online

Tags: javascript, web-services, titanium, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I want to add/retrieve data from MS Dynamics CRM Online 2011 using pure Javascript. I've searched whole day but could only find to do this with Dynamics SDK, C#, VB or JScript.

Is there any way to do this in pure javascript? I just need to find a web service to send/ get data to/from but couldn't find it. Is there any such web service or api exists??? Please help I am totally confused!!! Thanks.

Comment: Are you running the javascript from within CRM itself?  Or are you doing it from another website?

Comment: No actually I want to do this from a mobile application where the user will enter the data and send to CRM Online. I am using Appcelerator Titanium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two ways to interact with Javascript and CRM is via either OData, or SOAP services.  The easiest method is to use OData if possible.

The problem you're going to run into is Authentication with Odata.  [OData Access is not supported outside of CRM javascript and Silverlight](http://pogo69.wordpress.com/2012/12/01/crm-2011-odata-rest-and-the-querystring/).  (Although I use LinqPad to create my Odata queries, and it queries CRM with it just fine, so I'm not sure what that's all about)

The common method for getting around this is writing your own Webservice that authenticates to CRM, and then uses the SDK to retrieve and update the data, exposing it to you in a restful manner.

As Guido points out, you should be able to use SOAP requests from Java, but I've only ever done this from within CRM as well, and I'm not sure what authentication issues you will face as well.

Comment: It means I must use Jscript and Dynamics SDK environment in any case and there is no api or web service available to pure javascript. Am I right?

Comment: OData endpoint isn't available outside CRM Context, but this doesn't mean that is not possible to query CRM only with JavaScript, SOAP endopoint can be used (of course isn't the easy way)

Comment: @GuidoPreite Can you give me some direction? For now I've to just "add new leads" and "Get existing Leads" to show them to user.

Comment: @MuhammadQasim I kindly advice against using only JavaScript against CRM Web Services from an external application (specially with CRM Online), is better to create a .NET web service that will act as proxy between CRM and your application

Comment: @GuidoPreite Ok, I got it. This is one option. Any other options in your mind that you can show me if you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

If required as mentioned by others you CAN connect using SOAP (probably not recommended but as you want to know). If you don't know how to use SOAP/JavaScript then I suggest you read this:
[Simplest SOAP example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example-using-javascript)

To connect to CRM Online using Office 365 (all Windows Live accounts are migrating to Office 365) then you need to get security tokens then use that for your requests.

The following is a request for tokens in PHP that you should be able to refactor for JavaScript.

```
$TokenSOAP = '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                              <s:Header>
                                <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</a:Action>
                                <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:%s</a:MessageID>
                                <a:ReplyTo>
                                  <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
                                </a:ReplyTo>
                                <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">%s</a:To>
                                <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                                  <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                                    <u:Created>%sZ</u:Created>
                                    <u:Expires>%sZ</u:Expires>
                                  </u:Timestamp>
                                  <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-cdb639e6-f9b0-4c01-b454-0fe244de73af-1">
                                    <o:Username>%s</o:Username>
                                    <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">%s</o:Password>
                                  </o:UsernameToken>
                                </o:Security>
                              </s:Header>
                              <s:Body>
                                <t:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
                                  <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
                                    <a:EndpointReference>
                                      <a:Address>urn:crmapac:dynamics.com</a:Address>
                                    </a:EndpointReference>
                                  </wsp:AppliesTo>
                                  <t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType>
                                </t:RequestSecurityToken>
                              </s:Body>
                            </s:Envelope>';

        $TokenSOAP = sprintf($TokenSOAP, self::gen_uuid(), 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/RST2.srf',  self::getCurrentTime(), self::getNextDayTime(), $username, $password);
```

Change the Endpoint Reference address as required depending on your crm region

This will return two security tokens and a key identifier.

Then you need to do your add and retrieve. If you google "CRM 2011 SOAP" and the following four functions "Create", "Update", "Retrieve", and "RetrieveMultiple" you should get lots of SOAP samples for example:

http://www.mscrmconsultant.com/2012/07/create-update-delete-record-using.html