# PHP non blocking soap request

Tags: php, web-services, soap

After a user signs up on my website i need to send a soap request in a method that is not blocking to the user.  If the soap server is running slow I don't want the end user to have to wait on it.  Is there a way I can send the request and let my main PHP application continue to run without waiting from a response from the soap server?  If not, is there a way to set a max timeout on the soap request, and handle functionality if the request is greater than a max timeout?

Edit:
I would ideally like to handle this with a max timeout for the request.  I have the following:

```
//ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 1);
      $streamOptions = array(
              'http'=>array(
                'timeout'=>0.01
            )
      );

      $streamContext = stream_context_create($streamOptions);

      $wsdl   = 'file://' . dirname(__FILE__) . '/Service.wsdl';

        try{
          if ( file_get_contents( $wsdl ) ) {

              $this->_soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl,
                  array(
                      'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
                      'trace' => true,
                      'stream_context' => $streamContext
                  )
              );
              $auth = array('UserName' => $this->_username, 'Password' => $this->_password);
              $header = new SoapHeader(self::WEB_SERVICE_URL, "WSUser", $auth);
              $this->_soapClient->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));

          }//if
      }
      catch(Exception $e){
        echo "we couldnt connect". $e;
      }
$this->_soapClient->GetUser();
```

I set the timeout to 0.01 to try and force the connection to timeout, but the request still seems to fire off.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: php isn't designed for that.

Comment: PHP (in combination with GTK, or HTML(5)) is exactly designed and ready for that.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issues and have implemented solution !

I have implemented

```
SoapClient::__doRequest();
```

To allow multiple soap calls using

```
curl_multi_exec();
```

Have a look at this  [asynchronous-soap](https://github.com/Meabed/asynchronous-soap)

Answer (score 1):

Four solutions:

1. Use AJAX to do the SOAP -> [Simplest SOAP example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example-using-javascript)
2. Use AJAX to call a second PHP file on your server which does the SOAP (best solution imo)
3. Put the SOAP request to the end of your PHP file(s) (not the *deluxe* solution)
4. Use `pcntl_fork()` and do everything in a second process (I deprecate that, it might not work with every server configuration)

Depending on the way you implement this, PHP has plenty of timeout configurations,
 for example `socket_set_timeout()`, or `stream_set_timeout()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php)