# Access Web API Service using SOAP request

Tags: json, web-services, soap, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am working on an Web service project using .Net Web API.

I can call my service by using Http post. Is there any possibilities to call my restful web service using SOAP request?

Comment: The ASP.NET Web API allows you to build RESTful applications on the .NET Framework. Why would you want to use it for SOAP calls?

Comment: I think if you need soap you should use WCF not web API

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simplest SOAP example using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example-using-javascript)