# Can we add service reference to multi-device hybrid App?

Tags: javascript, web-services, typescript, visual-studio-cordova

So the Question is pretty straightforward. In my project, I need to consume services which are made in JAVA and they are in WSDL format. I need to make an app, which should be available for all the platforms. Since its essentially fetching service data and displaying, I think this Multi-Device Hybrid App project in Visual Studio should be best thing to go. But I'm not able to find how to add service reference in order to consume those services as I have been doing in other type of projects. Hence the Question: Can we even add service Reference to this type of project?

Answer (score 1):

Not in the way you can in a C# project, since there is no C# support.

You will have to find a javascript libaray that will do what you want. Or create and host a C# Webapi 'proxy' for your service so you can access it with JSON and jQuery from the app.

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example) can help when you want to do this from javascript directly

Comment: Not really because I've not done this myself, but this looks interresting: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12816/JavaScript-SOAP-Client

Comment: Checking the tool. Will let you know if it fixes my issue. Thankyou