# how to send a soap request and get the response using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web-services, soap

I want to send a soap request to the web service and get the response using javascript.
My web service is similar to the web service formed from this wsdl:
*[Currency Converter](http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL)*

The response is to be displayed on browser.

Can anyone help me through this??

Comment: Does this answer your question : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11404133/724913

Comment: Please see [this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example) which has a great example of how to do a simple SOAP request in JavaScript.

Comment: I am not able to get response. When I check for readyState in that function,  the process has readyState=1 i.e. only connection is established. Request is not received and and hence I do not get any response.