# Get ServerDateTime from client side

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I Have a javascript client side function to set the DateTime function.

```
function SetDateTime()
{
  var presentDate = new Date();
}
```

Instead I like to get the date from server side whenever SetDateTime() function is called.

in .cs I have this method to return server time.

```
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        protected static string GetCurrentTime() 
        {
           HiddenField hdnCurrentDateTime = new HiddenField();
           hdnCurrentDateTime.Value =  DateTime.Now.ToString();
           return hdnCurrentDateTime.Value;
        }
```

How to access this method from client side javascript? Thank you for your time.

Comment: make an ajax request

Comment: you can use `$.ajax({url: 'GetCurrentTime'})` thats all

Comment: [System.Web.Services.WebMethod] - have you seen that attribute? That's SOAP method, you can't just call it like that. Here is example of calling a SOAP web service question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example

Comment: Why not?  its a web  method and right candidate for an ajax call.

Comment: I've added link to a similar question. Try comparing the code from that answer with yours.. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

using ajax call  we can call webmethod like this

$.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "pagename/GetCurrentTime",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                }
            } 
        });

Answer (score 0):

As your method is *static* and assuming you have *hdDate* in your page,  try this:

```
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdDate" runat="server" 
value="<%# YourClassName.GetCurrentTime()%>" />
```