# soap response Firefox vs. soapui - same machine

Tags: web-services, firefox, soap, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

Why does a Soap response is blocked(I see `200 OK` but not response message) in FF due to

```
(Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

But not through SoapUI from the same machine(computer).

Is it that FF is blocking the response. If so , how can I make it work.

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example) to send Soap request through FF.

Comment: @SiKing  not a soapui question but someone using soapui might have ws knowledge to answer it.

Comment: anyone on this? please.