# SOAP Web Services in NativeScript

Tags: javascript, web-services, soap, cross-platform, nativescript

I am new in nativescript app development, I want to use SOAP web services in nativescript, i.e how to implement SOAP request & response in nativescript. Please give me suggestions, didn't find any way to implement SOAP, all search results are implemented in JavaScript code.

I do open github issues, please check - https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2284
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, their is no built in soap handling.  However, you can make you own in a couple steps.

1. NativeScript has built in http requests, and XMLHttpRequest and Fetch; this means you can query and receive back data you want from any service url. [http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/*http*.html](http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/_http_.html), https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/fetch, http://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/http

   In addition, their is a third party plugin called nativescript-apiclient which makes it easier to deal with http requests with changing parameters.  (i.e. http://somewhere/getdata/{token}/{data} where you can just pass in a token and data value...) See http://plugins.nativescript.rocks for different plugins available.
2. NativeScript has a XML parser built in, Soap responses are typically XML based.  So you can easily instantiate the xml engine to parse your soap requests (http://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/xml-parser)