# How to make a Soap call in React js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, soap

I have tried a few ways to make a Soap call through  Reactjs. But I am always facing some error in every approach. Can someone help me out here or kindly provide me with any small working example so that I could refer it?

I had tried using the **npm soap** and **easysoap** package but I am not able to succeed. Any working example is greatly appriciated.
I also tried the following way but it too doesn't work.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open('GET', '{My soap endpoint}', true);

// build SOAP request
var sr =
    '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="{My soap request}"'

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            alert('done. use firebug/console to see network response');
        }
    }
}
// Send the POST request
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
xmlhttp.send(sr);
```

Comment: You've got a missing quote in that `var sr = '...` declaration.

Comment: okay I got it ... can you please provide some example

Answer (score 9):

Both npm [*soap*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap) and [*easysoap*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/easysoap) are **Node.js** packages, which means that **they run on the server** but not on the client, where ReactJS lives.

So, if you want to call a soap service from the client, you can try [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11404133/2134166) of pure javascript or use a third-party tool like [jquery-soap](https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap).

Hope this helps :)