# Calling Java REST service with JS XMLHttpRequest causes CORS error

Tags: javascript, rest

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47581658/calling-web-service-using-xmlhttprequest-cors-issue) I am trying to call a Java+Kotlin Spring Boot REST service from JS.

However instead of XMLHttpRequest, I use fetch function:

```
function sendGetCountriesRequestToBackend(port) {
const endpoint = "/countries";
const url = 'http://localhost:' + port + endpoint;

const arguments = {
    method: "GET",
    mode: "no-cors",
    cache: "no-cache",
    credentials: "omit",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    redirect: "follow",
    referrer: "no-referrer"
};

fetch(url, arguments)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(getOnBackendFulfilled())
    .then(null, getOnBackendRejected());

 }
```

getOnBackendFulfilled() and getOnBackendRejected() are defined.

After calling sendGetCountriesRequestToBackend() I get SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

I suppose there's something wrong with arguments for fetch functions. Any ideas how to change them?

Comment: You should check what setting the [`mode` to `no-cors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode#Value) does and the consequences, ie unable to read the response

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I changed arguments to  {
        method: "GET",
        headers: [
            ["Content-Type", "application/json"],
            ["Content-Type", "text/plain"]
        ],
        credentials: "include"
    };

SAME ERROR :(