# Reading WSDL and printing the web methods in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wsdl

I'd like to read a WSDL from a URL and print the web methods available in the WSDL in Javascript or JQuery. Is there any way to do it ? Since the browser reads the "?WSDL" and prints the WSDL I hope there must be some way.

Sample URL :
https://soap.novice.com/user?WSDL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest SOAP example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's

https://github.com/strongloop/strong-soap

```
soap.createClient(wsdlpath, options, function(err, client) {
  // client has all the functions i.e., client.Login
  // simply iterate client keys that are functions.
  for(k of Object.keys(client)){
    console.log(typeof client[k]==="function" ? k : '')
  }
});
```

You most likely must use this server-side (node.js). I don't know of a SOAP client for the browser that I would trust to work for complicated WSDLs.