# How to set multiple headers data with XMLHttpRequest in async mode?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, http-headers

My api call requires me to pass the api key in the headers, but I'm getting error back from the api service `{"error":"2424452","message":"Invalid Api Key"}`

I know my api key is valid as I can make the same api call in Python just fine, example:

```
req = requests.Session()
req.headers.update({'x-api-key': 'my-api-key', 'X-Product': 'my-product-name'})
req.get(url)
```

But in javscript, the same call errors out. I believe I'm not setting the headers correctly or something?

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange=handleStateChange;
req.open("GET", "url", true);
req.setRequestHeader("Host", "api.domain.com", "x-api-key", "my-api-key", "X-Product", "my-product-name");
req.send();
```

- This `XMLHttpRequest` is not a browser call, rather in an application that support `XMLHttpRequest`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`setRequestHeader` sets **one** header and takes **two** arguments (the name and the value).

If you want to set multiple headers, then call `setRequestHeader` multiple times. Don't add extra arguments to the first call.

Answer (score 8):

In case you don't want to set multiple headers explicitly you can use

```
function setHeaders(headers){
  for(let key in headers){
    xhr.setRequestHeader(key, headers[key]) 
  }
}
setHeaders({"Host":"api.domain.com","X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest","contentType":"application/json"})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
downloadReportFile(id, query): Observable<Object[]> {
var url = `${environment.baseUrl}report?report_name=${id}${query}`;

return Observable.create(observer => {

  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open('GET', `${url}`, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader(environment.AUTH_TOKEN_HEADER_KEY, 'Bearer '+ 
  localStorage.getItem(environment.AUTH_TOKEN_STORE_KEY));
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {

        let filename = "Claim_Report.csv"
        var contentType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
        var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], { type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8" });
        if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {

          window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
          return;
        }

        const blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const tempLink = document.createElement('a');
        tempLink.style.display = 'none';
        tempLink.href = blobURL;
        tempLink.setAttribute('download', filename);

        if (typeof tempLink.download === 'undefined') {
          tempLink.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        }
        document.body.appendChild(tempLink);
        tempLink.click();
        document.body.removeChild(tempLink);
        setTimeout(() => {
          // For Firefox it is necessary to delay revoking the ObjectURL
          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL);
        }, 100);
      } else {
        observer.error(xhr.response);
      }
    }
  }
  xhr.send();

});
 }
```