# Is it possible to send a SOAP API Call via a custom HTML tag in Google Tag Manager

Tags: soap, google-tag-manager

I'm looking to send a SOAP API call to fetch some data to include in another tag. I could not find any working examples of a basic SOAP request made via custom HTML in Google Tag Manager, so I was wondering if this is possible or if someone has even tried to do this.

Comment: GTM can do everything that can be done via JavaScript, and evidently it is possible to write a SOAP client in JS. One example is this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example. In the bit that checks for a response status 200 you would add a push to the dataLayer with the part of the response that you want to use as a variable in other tags.

Comment: I saw this and thought it may work, but wasn't 100% sure. Thanks for confirming this for me.

Comment: One issue I getting after trying this out is responseStatus  == 0 and responseText == ''. I believe this is due to CORS. Anyone have any ideas if this is still feasible due to CORS?