# SoapClient in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, soap

I have this code in PHP and I need to do it in React

```
$consult = new SoapClient('My webPage');    
    $response = $consult->consultJob($name,$id);
```

Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: May be duplicated by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example, have you checked this out?

Answer (score 0):

The PHP SoapClient is a server side action.
When you say "do it in React", i'm assuming you mean the browser?
So you would not typically do this in the browser directly, but in a nodejs runtime on the server using a package like [soap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap)

Their example in the docs:

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'http://example.com/wsdl?wsdl';
var args = {name: 'value'};
soap.createClientAsync(url).then((client) => {
    return client.MyFunctionAsync(args);
}).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to do the request in the frontend

Comment: Well, I SOAP request is essentially a POST request with a SoapAction header,
So you can just use JS fetch API and add the soapAction header to it:

const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('SOAPAction', 'consultJob');