# link backend to frontend using Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, angular, token

I am currently working on a project, where I have to create the front end of an already existing backend project, this project already have the front end done with Angular, and I am trying to do the same thing using React, but lo link the front with the back I am not really sure how to.
this is the code of environment to link front with back from the Angular version.

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  backendURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:7778/',
  authentification : {
    username: 'user',
    password: 'c000000f-00a9-00c6-aff0-7b66d975d000',
    token: '##########################'
  }
};
```

Comment: You mean you want to access the backend API from the react frontend?

Comment: yes, exactly that

Comment: are you comfortable with react?

Comment: just started learning it kinda 1 month ago, i am getting familiar with it

Comment: Alright, you need to learn consuming rest APIs in react.

Comment: i learned about it, but the problem here is that my API does not have a clear URL, it is using authentication by Token

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch data using axios and send what credentials you want to get response.

Example:

```
axios.get(backendURL, {
    username: 'user',
    password: 'c000000f-00a9-00c6-aff0-7b66d975d000',
    token: '##########################'
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

To established the communication between the frontend and the backend parts , you can use:

- The **fetch** javascript native function , follow this example : [fetch-example](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/access-data-from-an-external-api-into-a-react-component)
- Using an npm package like **axios** to make a http request : for that follow this example : [axios example](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-axios-react)

I hope that can be halpful to resolve your issue.

Comment: this the code i used as a service
import axios from 'axios'
const GET_CUSTOMER_DETAILS_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:7778/api/v1/getCustomerDetail?000000a-0a00-0000-00ec-00c01d129600';

class GetCustomerDetails {

    getCustomerDetails(){
        return axios.get(GET_CUSTOMER_DETAILS_URL);
    }
}

export default new GetCustomerDetails();

Comment: yes, and what is the result returned by this function , use console.log to show what happen inside your function.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()                                           Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)                                                                                        those two errors

Comment: one thing , is that the back end is extracting informations from a wsdl file

Comment: so you need  on your back-end part convert the wsdl to json and check if it's working correctly using Postman after that implementit to your front-end part .

Comment: i tested it using SOAPUI and it works perfectly, i know it works because it had no problem in the Angular version

Comment: Both npm soap and easysoap are Node.js packages, which means that they run on the server but not on the client, where ReactJS lives.

So, if you want to call a soap service from the client, you can try this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example/11404133#11404133 of pure javascript or use a third-party tool like jquery-soap.

Hope this helps :)